# setTimeout creates an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to display different images randomly one by one by changing the src of the img tag.

```
<img src="dravid-young.jpg" width="350" height="460">
<script type="text/javascript">

var a= new Array ("dravid-childhood.jpg", "dravid-young.jpg", "Jellyfish.jpg", "Tulips.jpg" , "Lighthouse.jpg" , "Penguins.jpg");

$(document).ready(function(){
    var rand = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)];
    changeimage(a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)]);
});


function changeimage(imag)
{
    $("img").attr("src",imag);
    setTimeout(changeimage(a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)]), 5000);
}

</script>
```

But it looks like created an infinite loop, the page keep on loading!!

Comment: ... because you're calling `changeimage` each time in the `setTimeout`

Comment: Your `changeimage` function unconditionally calls `changeimage` -- what did you expect? Your code doesn't actually call `setTimeout` until `changeimage` returns -- which it never does.

Comment: Not to mention that you're trying to pick a random image index 3 times in your code when it's only required once

Comment: What do you mean by : "the page keep on loading" ?

Comment: You are doing a recursion!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass a function that invokes your function instead of invoking your function directly.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    changeimage(a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)]);
}, 5000);
```

You were invoking `changeimage` immediately, which does an immediate recursion instead of waiting.

By passing a function which invokes `changeimage`, it will  wait for `5000ms` before invoking it.

---

To be clear, I was just replacing the erroneous code above. The rest should stay in place. Here's the final example.

```
function changeimage(imag) {
    $("img").attr("src",imag);

    setTimeout(function() {
        changeimage(a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)]);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't pass any return value, because a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` exception is thrown before from the recursion :-)

Comment: @Bergi: You're right. I already updated. Conceptually it would if it were ever allowed to return, but it never gets to that point with the recursive call.

Comment: Thanks user2736012, but I want to display image repeatedly it change the image only once.

Comment: @raju:  You understand that I just replaced the code that's inside the `changeimage` function, right? I just left out the `function changeimage(imag) { $("img").attr("src",imag);` part to keep it short.

Comment: Yes user2736012, You got it. I didn't. But now It's fine. thanks. Your first line of the answer is the best description for the problem. "Pass a function that invokes your function instead of invoking your function directly." Once again thank you user2736012.

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function from within the same function it creates a loop, and if you don't stop it, it's an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks VoronoiPotato, the problem is I misunderstand the setTimeout function usage.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling changeimage in each changeimage call so you'll face a loop.

But you are executing a function each interval so you can use a `setInterval`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval

Like:

```
var a = new Array("http://placehold.it/200x200", "http://placehold.it/500x500", "http://placehold.it/300x300", "http://placehold.it/400x400", "http://placehold.it/300x300", "http://placehold.it/200x200");

var intervalID = window.setInterval(changeimage, 1000);

function changeimage() {    
    $("img").prop("src", a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)]);    
    console.log($("img").prop("src"))
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Xggb5/2/

Comment: Yes, `setInterval` fits a lot better in this case.

Comment: Added better example :-)

Comment: Thanks friends, it seems like I misunderstand the usage of setInterval function, thanks user2736012 your code works fine. but it changes the image only once, I want the image to be changed repeatedly for every 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Irvin Dominin aka Edward.